# Meaning of room numbers in The Matrix Reloaded

Tags: the-matrix, the-matrix-reloaded

The Matrix Reloaded starts at a room `303` where Neo dies in front of it, and the room number of Neo is `101`. I want to know what's its meaning. Is there any relation between `101` and `303`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There have been some theories floating around on the internet....

George Orwell's [1984](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four):

> [A tribute](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0133093/trivia) to George Orwell's Room 101 in 1984, where a prisoner is
> subjected to their worst phobia, and has subsequently been used in
> popular culture to signify a room where an item can be placed to never
> be again found. Neo has in turn been placed in room 101 by the
> machines, as they do not want 'The One' to be discovered.

Computers (binary):

> [101 actually appears](http://thematrix101.com/matrix/faq.php) a number of times in all three films, and though
> no one knows exactly what it means (if anything), the popular
> explanation is this: 101 is binary for 5 (which to a computer is the
> sixth number because computers count from 0), and the events of the
> three films take place in the 6th interation of the Matrix. Neo is the
> sixth One, this is the sixth time the machines have destroyed Zion,
> etc. We learn that this is the sixth iteration from The Architect's
> conversation.

and of course, there is the obvious: Trinity is in room 303 (Trinity = 3), and Neo's apartment number is 101 (Neo, "The One" = 1).

Comment: And the roman numeral for 5 is V, as in Vendetta... :)

Answer (score -2):

The error 303 is a standard HTTP redirect, like the bullets were "redirected" to a new location.

Matrix is a film full of computer & web analogies, this is no different.

Comment: Without a source this is just [wild mass guessing](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WildMassGuessing).

Comment: It is not just guessing, it doesn't even make much sense from a technical point of view. 301 or 302 are *much* more commonly HTTP redirects - There wouldn't be any reason to use 303 here.

Comment: @dirkk *"In an office on the fourth floor (room 404), they placed the World Wide Web's central database: any request for a file was routed to that office, where two or three people would manually locate the requested files and transfer them, over the network, to the person who made that request."*  Error code 404 is [actually from the room number to go to](http://www.room404.com/page.php?pg=homepage).  For a technical communication trying to be artistic, someone might draw from 303 for its symmetry instead of its commonality.

Answer (score -2):

around the premiere of the movie i heard that some of the names reference classic analog synthesizers. Roland [SH-101](http://www.vintagesynth.com/roland/sh101.php) and [TB-303](http://www.vintagesynth.com/roland/303.php) (a.k.a 101 & 303) are among the most cultic ones. not confirmed, though.

Answer (score -3):

Alistair Crowley has a book that tells you the meaning of numbers.
I read the numbers in movies are based on his evil writings!
http://energyfanatics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Seminar6-Decoding-Occult-Messages-in-Matrix1.pdf

Comment: Just dropping a link isn't really an answer.